# Swiper fluid image scaling

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Using [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/), I have a very standard setup:

```
<div class="swiper-container">

    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="image/whatever.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="image/whatever.jpg"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="image/whatever.jpg"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>

</div>
```

Same with CSS:

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;

}

.swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

What I'd wish, though, is that I could decrease the size of the window and have the container automatically adjust its size. As it is, only the `width` is actually adjusted, the `height` stays the same, no matter if I use `auto` or a percent value.

The result is that my images get squashed, when I'd like them to retain their proportions.

How can I achieve this? (CSS or JS solutions are both perfectly fine).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
.yourFluidImage {
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
     height:auto !important;
}

.swiper-slide {
     height:auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.swiper-wrapper {
  height:auto !important;
  width:100%;
}
```